# Error with ionic on cordova build android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-android

I'm trying to build an android app with ionic but i have theses issues, don't really know what's going wrong.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> /Users/Imade/hellotag/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/cordova/plugin/BrowserTab.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
> import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
> ^
> symbol:   class CustomTabsIntent
> location: package android.support.customtabs
> /Users/Imade/hellotag/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
> import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
> ^
> /Users/Imade/hellotag/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
> @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
> ^
> symbol:   class RequiresApi
> location: class IonicWebViewEngine.ServerClient
> /Users/Imade/hellotag/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/cordova/plugin/BrowserTab.java:104: error: package CustomTabsIntent does not exist
> Intent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build().intent;
> ^
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> 4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

cordova platform version android
Installed platforms:
android 8.1.0
ios 6.2.0

- androidx installed.

ionic -v
6.16.3

java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_272-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: what version of java are you using?

Comment: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_272-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)